# Should we rename the hermeneutical-approaches tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't much like the [hermeneutical-approaches](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hermeneutical-approaches) tag.  For one thing, it's too long.  I would like to change it to [hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hermeneutics).  But that could be confusing since a naive user might wonder why all questions aren't tagged that way as it's the name of the site.

Another suggestion is [approaches](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approaches) which has an elegance to it, but might not be immediately obvious to someone groping for the proper tag for a question that's not [exegesis](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exegesis).

Looking at the [hermeneutical-approaches](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hermeneutical-approaches) questions is there a tag (or tags) that would be a better label?

Comment: Before we can really determine whether this is possible, we need to consider whether to remove the blacklist on "hermeneutics".  I've created a new post [here](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/155/15) in order to address this.

Comment: See my answer [to the other question](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/155/should-we-remove-the-blacklist-on-the-hermeneutics-tag/161#161) for why I think it doesn't need to be renamed 'hermenutics'. I suppose some other rename might work, but I think the specificity is important and that 'approaches' or 'hermenetics' are too broad to refer to what the tag should be attached too.

Answer (score 3):

We can't make it [hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hermeneutics) because of the site-wide block on that tag.  (I've already tried.)

We *can* look into getting this removed, since this site isn't exclusively about hermeneutics.  However, it will take a bit of effort from the SE people.  And they are a tough crowd to convince.  Many (some?) of them are blatantly opposed to any tags of this sort.

Comment: Would it be easier to change the name of the site? ;-)

Comment: As the creator of that tag, I would like to mention that the blacklist was not the "reason" for the appendage, it was because I actually wanted the tag to be for questions _about_ the different hermeneutical approaches out there.

Comment: @Caleb That's very enlightening.  So, is there anything that "hermeneutics" would cover that "hermeneutical-approaches" wouldn't cover?

Comment: @Richard: Yes: all the questions that require the _use_ of hermeneutics to answer them but are more about the product than the tool ... exactly the kind of things that _don't_ need a meta tag.

Comment: @Caleb Wouldn't the use of hermeneutics result in exegesis?  (I may still be fuzzy on the terminology here.)

Comment: @Richard: Yes it would. Which is why we don't need it as a tag; it's overly broad.

Comment: Oh, I see!  Tagging with "hermeneutics" because someone wants the application of hermeneutics.  Yeah, great point!

Answer (score 1):

Great suggestion; I don't see any questions tagged as [hermeneutical-approaches](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hermeneutical-approaches) that wouldn't be fine tagged [hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hermeneutics).

The site's name is a bit of a problem for me as well; most of the questions on this site don't even fit the named topic. But I'd be happy with making the tag simply [hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hermeneutics)